# Functions in Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a simple macro to convert lower case letters to upper case.
Whenever I run it it gives an error message: "Compile Error: Can't find project or library"

It does not recognize the UCase and Format functions. How do I resolve this?

```
Sub text001()
Dim x As String
    x = "is lois a good girl"
    x = UCase(x)
    mystr = Format("this is good", ">")
End Sub
```

Comment: Your "Function" (which is a sub) what does it actually do? Can you explain what you are trying to acheive?

Comment: This message generally occurs when there's a reference set in your VBProject which is not found.  Likely it's nothing to do with either UCase or Format.  In the VB Editor go to Tools>>References and look for any marked with "MISSING"

Comment: I pasted this Sub into Excel 2010 and it ran satisfactorily. I agree that it might be something to do with your VBProject, as suggested by @TimWilliams.

Comment: have you tried saving, closing, and re-opening Excel. I know it sounds terribly obvious but this is how I have resolved that problem in the past.

Answer (score 0):

when I come up against this, I have found that saving, closing and re-opening frequently resolves the issue.

Failing that, in the References dialog, add another reference, save and close.

When you re-open, your references should be repaired.